# Google Account without a mobile number

Tags: google-account, account-management, mobile, verification

I would like to make a Google account (email, youtube etc.) and it requests a mobile number. It makes sense, so it can stop robots making spam designated email accounts, but I don't own a mobile and I don't want to be forced into buying one simply to make a Google account.Is there any other form of verification that I can take?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I believe there is. When creating an account you can choose for not filling in a phone number. In order to check you're not a robot Google will ask you to complete a captcha code.

This is what I saw, maybe it is different in your region/device? Please let me know!